# Why (true || false && false) evaluates to true?

Tags: elixir

Why following expression evaluates to "true"?

```
true || false && false
```

Comment: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/pages/Operators.md

Comment: && has a higher priority level than ||  thus `true || false && false` evaluates as `true || (false && false)`

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: In general if there's any ambiguity in such a statement, adding parentheses to insure order of evaluation is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in elixir '&&' has higher precedence than '||'.

Comment: "stronger associativity" isn't quite correct.  To be correct, `&&` has higher precedence than `||` hence the `false && false` is evaluated first.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
(true || false) && false # => false
```